# 429 ответ от сервера при парсинге

Tags: python-3.x, requests, bs4

Пытаюсь парсить https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/ при помощи BeautifulSoup. Собираю ссылки на каждую крипту, а затем с каждой ссылки забираю название и стоимость. Получается спарсить 10-15 первых ссылок, а затем сервер выдает 429 ответ. Пытался передавать в GET-запрос заголовки user-agent и accept, использовал свободные прокси `requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, proxies={'http':choice(PROXY)})`, никакого результата, также 10-15 ссылок позволяет спарсить и все, 429 ответ. Можно ли как-то обойти это?

Comment: У них есть API: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/, на бесплатном плане 10тыс. запросов в месяц.

Comment: @ГеннадийП спасибо, попробую

Comment: параметр proxies в requests задан не верно. в словаре определяются протоколы для которых нужно использовать прокси. ты указываешь http, а сайт использует https. это раз

Comment: можешь попробовать сделать так, правильно настроить работу с прокси, рандомный юзер-агент. в принципе и все. ну можешь еще добавить заголовок Connection: close.